# Unexpected token A

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have this function:

```
function returnVehicleByValue(vehicleValue){
    $.get("inc/ajax/selectMojaVozila.php",
        {vehicleValue:vehicleValue},
        function(html){
            var vehicle = JSON.parse(html);


        }
    );
}
```

But when I execute it it gives me the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A
```

It comes from the line:

```
var vehicle = JSON.parse(html);
```

I don't understand why I checked everything and it seems alright.

"html" returns an array I checked that
When I say alert(html) it pops up "Array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because jQuery automatically parses the return. If it determines it to be JSON, it will parse it to JSON. You can check this by doing `console.log(typeof html)` in your callback. If it's pre-parsed by jQuery, it prints `object`.

From [`$.get()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> **dataType**
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).

Comment: So I call it like html.name?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! If console.log(html) Returns just "Array" does it mean it's empty?

Comment: @Xegano you can check the value of `html.length` to see if it contains anything. Objects from JSON can be an Array or Object, depending on the JSON returned.

Comment: It does contain stuff but is there a way like in php (print_r) To see what it contains?

Comment: @Xegano You can check in the network tab on the browser's debugging tools. It's F12 on most browsers. You'll see all requests sent and received by the browser. Find the one generated by your AJAX and check the response.

Comment: Well it only says Array and html.length says 5

Answer (score 0):

When you use the $.get function you don't have to parse the response - it will be parsed automatically.